# I want to make rich text editing field in flutter like Tumblr

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to achieve text editor behavior same as Tumblr where you can add images, gifs, text, and other attachments in only one text field and drag them to change their positions. I want to do it in flutter for iOS and android both. I tried every rich text editor for flutter from pub.dev but no one is doing the right job for this behavior. Can someone able to help me to make this layout?
Thanks in advance
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLObL.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKRue.png

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.